# Reading text from a bat file in to python

Tags: python, batch-file

Is it possible to read a line from a batch file in to a python script?

I have a .bat file that contains the following:

```
@echo off
rem generated from template 

Set A_version= 9.0.0
set App_name = test
...
```

How can i grab the A_version from this .bat file and store it as a variable.
I would somehow need to read the bat file and look for A_version and store the value of it which is 9.0.0 in to a variable in python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `open()`, `read()`/`readline()`/`readlines()`, `close()`

Comment: …just to let you know, _as it was partially mentioned by Stephan_, your .bat file sets a varaible, "%A_version%", to the value " 9.0.0". Also is sets a variable, "%App_name %", to the value " test". I'm assuming those spaces are not really required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in open('name.bat', 'r'):
    if 'A_version' in line:
        A_version = line.split('=')[-1].strip()
        break
```

This will search for the string, assign the value to a variable of the same name and break out of the loop in case the variable is referenced later in the bat, we don't need that.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! All other answers are greatly appreciated too, but this seemed to solve another problem i faced in which the variable was referenced later on in the bat. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
with open('file.bat', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'A_version' in line:
            value = line.split('=')[1].strip()
```

Comment: Actually, it can even be `for line in open(...):`

Comment: Yes it does, the file is no longer opened after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it from batch:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('type "yourbatfile.bat"^|findstr /b /i "Set A_version="') do set var=%%a
```

find the correct line and split it by `=`. If needed, you can strip the space with

```
set var=%var: =%
```

Comment: Thanks but i would like to do it from python

Answer (score 0):

Read through the file. Look for the variable name in each line. Where you find it, convert the value after '=' to an int, then assign to your python variable.

```
a_ver_val = 0
f = open("that.bad",'r')
for item in f:
    if "A_version" in item:
        a_ver_val = int( item.split("=", 1)[1] )

f.close()
```

You can write more efficient code, but keeping it simple here so you have your answer.