# How to access Batch Script variables in python?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a bat file which sets values to variables and I need to use those variables in python script.

env.bat:

```
SET USERNAME=username
SET PASSWORD=password
```

I need the above variables to be used in python script. I've tried the below but I get *None* as output.

login.py

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['env.bat'])
print(os.getenv('USERNAME'))
```

Could you please help where I'm wrong or any other way I could achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only need to read the username and password or save them later as well?
You might find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914880/reading-text-from-a-bat-file-in-to-python

Comment: firstly, never have spaces between variables, values and the `=` it should be `set "USERNAME=username"` then to send it, you need to get the python script to first read input arguments, but then simply send it from the batch file to pythin script as `python script.py %USERNAME% %PASSWORD%`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read windows environment variable value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496748/how-to-read-windows-environment-variable-value-in-python)

Comment: @GittingGud, thank you for the link. I had the same thing in mind but it's more like searching for a string and finding it's value followed by **=**. Is there a way similar to calling the bat file which sets variables and use those variables like `%USERNAME%` in batch script ?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I have had a look at it and tried the answer. The output is _None_ . I'm posting my python script in question so that you may help correcting it.

Comment: @Krishy if your .bat file does always have the same structure you can just read each line into a string and then split the string after the "=": yourstring.split("=")

Comment: @GittingGud It works perfectly fine. I'm also interested to know if there is a way I can call the bat file and use variables directly as in batch scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/v:on', '/q', '/c', 'env.bat', '&echo(!USERNAME!&echo(!PASSWORD!'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
username, password = stdout.splitlines()
print(username)
print(password)
```

Since `env.bat` does not use `setlocal`, the environmental variables
will be available in the same process of `cmd`, after `env.bat` is run.
This allows `echo` the values of `!USERNAME!` and `!PASSWORD!` to the
stdout stream.

Options of `cmd`:

- `/v:on` enables delayed expansion.
- `/q` sets echo off.
- `/c` runs the following command string.

Note:

- Tested in *Python 2* and *Python 3*. *Python 2* is missing support for a
  context manager with `subprocess` so a `with` statement was not used.
- The `USERNAME` environmental variable is a builtin name.
  Changing it without good reason may create unexpected issues.
- As delayed expansion is enabled, use of `!` in `env.bat` may need
  to be escaped, else `!` may be omitted when `cmd` parses the file.
  `call echo` in the command line could avoid the enabling of delayed
  expansion if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.getenv()` you are trying to get an environment variable. So, you need to set an environment variable in your batchfile. This can be done, using the `SETX` command, as described in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc755104(v=ws.10)).

```
SETX USERNAME=username
SETX PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: I've tried above solution, unfortunately I still get _None_ as my output. And one thing is that I don't want to change my code in bat file which is used by other batch scripts.